# After removing DOM element from child component when refreshing props gets error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**CODE**

https://github.com/bostonmacosx/MTBCRM/tree/main/mtbcrm_react/src/components

PARENT COMPONENT: MainScreen

Child Components: Userlist on the left and People next to it.

I have a list which when clicked sends the information to the child components.
[image: Click on Robert]

When I then click on the X I run a javascript routine in the child component which removes the phone number from the database which works fine....

[image: Phone number removed.]

When I go to click on one of the names in the List....which run the get userDetails in the MainScreen component and updates the props for the people component I get

[image: Error Message]

Not sure why the react app is erroring out at this piont. It was fine until I removed the phone number DIV with javascript after clicking the "X"

Not sure why.

Comment: Show your code. People can't guess what you've written.

Comment: @super sorry GIT available at top

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask] and how to make a [mre]. Don't give external links to code, include it in the question with proper formatting.